# Custom denied.gsp styles not rendering

Tags: css, grails, layout, spring-security, gsp

I am using the spring-security-core plugin and I have created a custom **denied.gsp** page under */views/login/denied.gsp*.  If I go to the page directly via */login/denied* I can see that the layout was applied.  However, if I attempt to access a restricted page and I am routed to the **denied.gsp** it just renders the exact html without processing the layout.

```
<html><head>
        <title>Denied</title>
        <meta name="layout" content="main">
    </head>
    <body>
        <section class="breadcrumb p07">
            <p><a href="/">Home</a> Denied</p>
        </section>
        <section class="content">
            <p>Sorry, you're not authorized to view this page.</p>
        </section>

</body></html>
```

I have these set to false, so that everything is not locked down by default:

```
grails.plugin.springsecurity.rejectIfNoRule = false
grails.plugin.springsecurity.fii.rejectPublicInvocations = false
```

AdminController:

```
@Secured(['ROLE_ADMIN'])
class AdminController {

    def index() { 

    }
}
```

So for example, I am logged in as ROLE_USER and then go to /admin, it correctly denies me.  Yet, it has no styling on the page.

There are no additional rules regarding css, js, etc.

I can't figure out why the styling is not applied in this case.  Any ideas?

Comment: @JoshuaMoore yes, I am

Comment: Have you verified that there is unrestricted access to the CSS and other styling related elements? It would be helpful if you posted your request mappings. Considering everything by default is completely locked down.

Comment: I'm assuming that you haven't messed with the `adh.errorPage` property in your config?

Comment: @RobStemen no, I haven't changed that property

Comment: @adavis I had the same problem. Seems it is bug. Also here provided some workaround solution. http://jira.grails.org/browse/GPSPRINGSECURITYCORE-253

Comment: @emilan, if you post the work-around I will accept your answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

At first get familiar with this one https://github.com/grails-plugins/grails-spring-security-core/issues/177

As a work-around I would recommend you below mentioned steps.

In your `UrlMappings.groovy` make modification:

```
"500"(controller: "error", action: "denied")
```

In your `Config.groovy` file override `errorPage` property

```
grails.plugin.springsecurity.adh.errorPage = null
```

And add action in your controller:

```
def denied() {
    render(view: '/login/denied')
}
```

This works for me.